# How to intercept and translate USB events

Tags: controller, usb, device-driver

I would like to use the Philips LFH-2330 to view images (with Windows Image Viewer or another viewer such as IrfanView, etc.)

The LFH-2330 is a foot controller with four pedals (see [here](http://www.aaaaudio.net/lfh2330.html) for example) used to control audio playback software for transcription. It comes with its own driver and software.

The simplest setup for me would be a piece of software that would catch pedal events from the controller and trigger keyboard events instead (right pedal => right arrow, left pedal => left arrow).

This simple setup however needs the viewing application to be in focus in order for it to work.

A better solution would be to be able to control the viewing application from the foot controller without the application being (nor coming) into focus, so that I can type with my hands and paginate with my feet at the same time. (But this can also be achieved with two computers).

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's more or less hacking right? The following might work on Windows ~~~

Anyway the following can be done

- Understand the USB commands from the
  controller (by using usb-tracer)
- Write a filter driver to intercept
  the USB IRP, and generate such IRP
- Generate IRP from your filter driver,
  on getting commands from your input,
  say, Keyboard

For doing the above things, you should know about WDM model very well. IOCTL etc ~~~

Comment: Well your answer is probably the correct one, but I found myself quite unable to pull it off... I ended up buying this instead: http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/fs-savant-elite.htm which works very well.