# Read status and parameters from a UV printer in C/C++

Tags: c++, printing, usb, printer-control-language

I have a large UV printer based on Ricoh GEN5 printheads and I'm correctly able to print my files by using the proprietary software over USB communication on Windows 10.

I would like to understand if there is any chance to query the printer over USB in order to get its status or any other useful information such as the printhead speed, its current position, and so on.

I'm able to do this by using the vendor software (it is a chinese company), but I need to implement this function in my C/C++ program in order to run some statistics on the printer performance.
Is it possible to do that? I tried to search on google, but I found nothing.

[image]

Comment: I think it's hard because transferring between vendor's app and the device is private and rarely vendor public the format of data for you. Or you can sniff and analyze message to know format of a message which is according to your action on the GUI app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137206/how-do-i-intercept-messages-from-a-usb-device-on-linux

Comment: Thank you! Sniffing the data could be a solution even if it will be hard to find all the packets.

Comment: I tried to sniff it and then I've used Wireshark but it's almost impossible to understand what is exchanged over the USB.